# php No database selected

Tags: php, mysql

Have been trying to figure out for about an hour why, when I enter log in information on the index page, then click submit, it says "No database selected" on the Login.php page. Any advice would be much appreciated, thanks!

The connect.php file

```
<?php
$host= "127.0.0.1";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "users";

mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db);
?>
```

The login.php file

```
<?php
session_start();

//Login Script

//Make sure have access to database
include_once("connect.php");

//If the post of the username (username has been submitted on login form)
if (isset($_POST["username"])) {

//set variables
$usernmame = $_POST["password"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

//Select the column from the users table where the username is the username entered aps same for password
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1";

//Run quety
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
    echo "Success";


}

else {
    echo "Again";
}
}
```

The index file

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<head>
<title>Login test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type"text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>

<div id="wrapper">
<h2>test log in</h2>

<?php
//If not logged in, display login formThe 
if(!isset($_SESSION["uid"])) {
    echo "<form action='Login.php' method='post'>
            Username: <input type='text' name='username' />&nbsp;
            Password: <input type='password' name='password' />&nbsp;
            <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Login'/>";
}

else {
    echo "<p>You are logged in as ".$_SESSION['username']." <a href='Logout.php'>Log out</a>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Migrate from `mysql_*` function to eg. `PDO`. Also, show us `include_onceTh` function.

Comment: Also, you are using wrong variable in `mysql_num_rows($res)`.

Comment: You really need to read [why not to use mysql_ functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: Yeah sorry I corrected those two, but mysql_connect should work??

Comment: you have a typo there `include_onceTh("connect.php");`  should be **include_once("connect.php");** ;-)

Comment: Yes I corrected this, but error still occurs :(

Comment: Post your corrected code please. don't you have another file named `Login.php`? do you use nix or win system as a host?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should stop using `mysql_*` functions.

But just to try to help you pass this obstacle for now try this way:

```
$db_link = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db, $db_link);
```

and then always use that `$db_link` like:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql, $db_link) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but I don't believe the [`mysql_connect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) function allows you to select the database. Try the following in your connect file. You should also consider switching to the MYSQLI functions which support selecting a database on connect.

```
mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db);
```

Comment: This is what it was originally isn't it?

Comment: @WebDev661 no there is a difference when call `mysql_connect`

Comment: @WebDev661 update your original post with updated code please

Answer (score 0):

The [`mysql_connect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)(note the deprecation warning on the page) function doesn't let you specify a default database. However the [`mysqli_connect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) function does.
Also the return value of [`mysql_select_db`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php) should be checked, to see if the database is actually selected.